# Como usar o querySelectorAll sem ter que especificar os elementos do array depois?

Tags: javascript

To tentando usar o querySelectorAll para ver quando os `<li>` é clicado e exibir o menu de cada 1 o problema é ter que ficar especificando o array, exemplo obj[0], para cada 1, eu queria saber se daria para fazer isso de forma mais automática? sem precisar especificar para cada `<li>` diferente?

html:

```
<ul class="obj-menu">
        <div class="obj-header">title</div>
        <li class="obj-item">
            <span class="obj-title">text1</span>
            <ul class="obj-menu-sub">
                <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 2</li>
                <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 3</li>
                <!-- <li class="obj-item-sub"></li> -->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="obj-item">
                <span class="obj-title">title 2</span>
                <ul class="obj-menu-sub">
                    <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 1</li>
                    <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 2</li>
                    <!-- <li class="obj-item-sub"></li> -->
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

O que eu consegui fazer ate agora em JS::

```
abreObj = document.querySelectorAll(".obj-item");
abreObj[1].addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var objSub = abreObj[1].querySelector(".obj-menu-sub");


    if(objSub.style.display == "block"){
        objSub.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        objSub.style.display = "block";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diferentemente do jQuery (que alguns diriam ser um pouco mais simples), quando você usa o método [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), um objeto [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList) é retornado, que é semelhante a um `array` e que contém todos os elementos selecionados.

Para adicionar um *event listener* cada um deles, é ideal que você use uma forma de iterar sobre cada elemento. No exemplo a seguir, vamos usar o [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```js
abreObjs = document.querySelectorAll('.obj-item')

abreObjs.forEach((abreObj) => {
  abreObj.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const objSub = abreObj.querySelector('.obj-menu-sub')

    // Ao invés de usar um if/else, vamos usar um operador ternário. :)
    objSub.style.display = objSub.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
  })
})
```

```html
<ul class="obj-menu">
  <div class="obj-header">title</div>
  <li class="obj-item">
    <span class="obj-title">text1</span>
    <ul class="obj-menu-sub">
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 2</li>
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 3</li>
      <!-- <li class="obj-item-sub"></li> -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="obj-item">
    <span class="obj-title">title 2</span>
    <ul class="obj-menu-sub">
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 1</li>
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 2</li>
      <!-- <li class="obj-item-sub"></li> -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### `NodeList === Array // false`

Note que apesar de serem semelhantes, o **objeto** `NodeList` **não é um `array`**. Se você precisar transformar um `NodeList` em `Array`, poderá optar por usar um dos dois métodos exemplificados a seguir.

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('a')

// Primeiro método de transformar um NodeList num Array:
const firstMethod = Array.from(nodeList)

// Segundo método de transformar um NodeList num Array:
const secondMethod = [...nodeList]

// Provando que `nodeList` não é um array:
console.log(nodeList instanceof Array, nodeList instanceof NodeList) // false, true
console.log(firstMethod instanceof Array, firstMethod instanceof NodeList) // true, false
console.log(secondMethod instanceof Array, secondMethod instanceof NodeList) // true, false
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
```

#### Referência:

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll);
- [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList);
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: Obg, realmente ajudou, a explicação foi muito claro e deu pra entender certinho!

Answer (score 3):

A forma mais simples é adicionar os ouvintes de evento dentro de um loop:

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(".obj-item")) {
    elememt.addEventListener("click",function(event){ ... })
}
```

Mas você pode adicionar o ouvinte no container e descobrir a origem do click:

```js
document.querySelector(".obj-menu").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  //O elemento clicado
  let objItem = event.target;
  console.log(objItem);
  
  //Caso clique no elemento com a classe obj-header ou obj-menu pode parar, só precisamos continuar se for em outro elemento
  if (objItem.classList.contains('obj-header') || objItem.classList.contains('obj-menu')) {
     return;
  }

  //Verifica se o elemento clicado possui a classe obj-item
  while (!objItem.classList.contains('obj-item')) {
    //Enquanto não, pega o próximo elemento acima
    objItem = objItem.parentElement;
  }
  
  //Aqui objItem é o elemento com classe obj-item mais próximo
  console.log(objItem);

  const objSub = objItem.querySelector(".obj-menu-sub");

  if (objSub.style.display == "block") {
    objSub.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    objSub.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="obj-menu">
  <div class="obj-header">title</div>
  <li class="obj-item">
    <span class="obj-title">text1</span>
    <ul class="obj-menu-sub">
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 2</li>
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 3</li>
      <!-- <li class="obj-item-sub"></li> -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="obj-item">
    <span class="obj-title">title 2</span>
    <ul class="obj-menu-sub">
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 1</li>
      <li class="obj-item-sub">texto 2</li>
      <!-- <li class="obj-item-sub"></li> -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Boa resposta com duas sugestões. Podias usar o `.closest()` do que o `while`.

Comment: Realmente interessante a forma como a sua resposta chega na solução! +1 :)

Comment: @Sergio nem lembrava dessa função, o único problema dela é que precisa do `match`, tem que adicionar alguns polyfills

Comment: @LuizFelipe interessante é, mas eu só usaria se eu precisasse manipular essa função em determinado momemto por algum motivo, a primeira forma é mais simples e mais performática